# Deprecated: mysql_pconnect

Tags: php

Can anybody help me to fix this error? I try with some solutions here but it appear another error in the index.php page. I asked the hosting company to downgrade the version but they don't accept.

> Deprecated: mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home2/mohamed/public_html/portal/includes/DBclass.php on line 7

```
class mysqlQueryClass {
    var $result,$resultNoRows;

    function dbConnect(){
        $dbConnect=mysql_pconnect(_DATA_BASE_HOST_, _DATA_BASE_USER_, _DATA_BASE_BASSWORD_)
        or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db(_DATA_BASE_NAME_)
        or die(mysql_error());
        return $dbConnect;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't want use mysqli or PDO, why don't you ignore the deprecate message?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions. Look into `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. Downgrade PHP to an old unsupported version is a bad idea.

Comment: This is not an error message, this is just a notice.

Comment: _"I try with some solutions here but it appear another error in the index.php page."_ What was the solution you tried and what was the other error message?

Comment: replaced all mysql to mysqli  only replace in the same file DBclass.php

Comment: *"replaced all mysql to mysqli only replace in the same file DBclass.php"* - if you're still including `mysql_` mixed in with `mysqli_` somewhere, those different mysql api's do not intermix. If you are using `mysqli_` somewhere, make sure the syntax is correct and are passing db connection to functions that require it.

Comment: i replaced in DBclass.php all mysql to mysqli  all now but appear now this error   ( Fatal error: Class 'mysqlQueryClass' not found in /home2/mohamed/public_html/portal/index.php on line 11   )   i must change all mysql to mysqli in index.php also ??

Comment: Did you change the name of that class? You need to do a proper refactoring of your code, not just replace `mysql` to `mysqli`.

Comment: yes only replaced not change anything else i dont know how to change the class

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to mysqli or suppress `E_DEPRECATED` messages:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

Comment: where i pot this code sit   error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

Comment: After `<?php`. Or, just change your php.ini file with that.

Comment: You can also do it in `.htaccess`: `php_value error_reporting <integer>`. Where `<integer>` is the value of `E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED`.

Comment: not fixed i dont know what can i do . if i can hide this message what can i do sorry sir